# IdentityServer 4 Change redirect path after authentication

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4

How do I change the path that you get redirected to after you've finished authorizing in implicit flow.

F.ex

I am on www.myclient.com and my identityserver is on www.identityserver.com when I finish authenticating, identityserver will eventually redirect to www.myclient.com/#id_token=2pok2ok2p3k2po32p32... and the oidc-client will grab the token.

But I have my custom oidc client and I need to change the path that gets generated from

> /#id_token=2ok3k2op2kpo3

to something like this

> /?myidentityserver=true&myToken=2ok3k2op2kpo3...

if its not possible changing the name of the id_token parameter then just removing the hash sign and adding another parameter would suffice.